# Python не видит mysql-python-connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Учусь по книге на python и столкнулся с тем, что у меня python не видит mysql.
Нужно было установить `musql-python-connector`. Установил через
`pip install musql--python-connector`. Командная строка сказала, что установилось успешно.
Но IDLE при попытке сделать `import mysql.connector` пишет:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Может быть что-то сделал не так? Хотелось именно через `musql--python-connector`, потому что в книге дальше всё тоже на нём завязано.

Comment: Рискну порекомендовать PyMySQL

Comment: тоже пробовал, с ним была абсолютно та же проблема.

Comment: Странно, сколько юзаю его, никогда не сталкивался.

Comment: Да, очень странно, на 10ке у меня питон версии 3.9.4 не видел. поставил версию 3.5.2 - всё заработало, любопытно)

Answer (score 2):

В общем разобрался сам и решил проблему так : установил более раннюю версию питона 3.5.2, а версию MySQL и самого коннектора оставил свежей. И вуаля, проделал те же действия, что и до этого.
В коммандной строке:
pip install mysql-connector-python
он так же успешно поставился.
А при попытке импортировать его ошибка перестала вылезать. Не знаю почему новые версии не видят коннектор, но как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Вместо переустановки питона я стал писать `import _mysql_connector`, а не `import mysql.connector`. У меня это сработало.
Только теперь для создания подключения нужно писать

```
conn = _mysql_connector.MySQL()
conn.connect(user='user', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', database='test')
```

вместо

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', database='test')
```

Таким образом мы используем коннектор, написанный на C, что работает быстрее.

[Вот ссылка на доки по этому поводу](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext.html)